# Matlab unable to call superclass method

Tags: matlab, oop, matlab-class

I'm new to Matlab and am facing some problems with calling superclass methods.

I've got this code:

Superclass test1:

```
classdef test1 < handle
    methods
        function obj = test1()
        end
        function test2(obj)
            disp(1);
        end
    end

end
```

Subclass test:

```
classdef test < test1 & handle
    properties
        foo = 1;
    end
    methods
        function obj = test()
            obj = obj@test1();
        end
        function a = bar(obj)
            superclasses(obj)
            test2@test1(obj)
        end
    end
end
```

The inheritance works correctly; the superclasses function shows `test1` as a superclass of `test`. However, when I call `test2@test1(obj)`, it returns an error:

> "@" Within a method, a superclass method of the same name is called by
>   saying method@superclass.  The left operand of "@" must be the method
>   name.

The `test`2 method obviously exists within the superclass `test1`, so I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @ syntax only if the method names in your superclass and child class are same and the call is within the child class method with the same name. Otherwise you can just call the method directly since there is no confusion. So instead of `test2@test1(obj)` just use test2(obj).

You also do not need to specify handle as a super class again in your child class.