# Memoize a method of a class in matlab

Tags: matlab, oop

I have some code from a collegue, and I want to add caching to one of the class methods without chancing the original code. I think I should simply overload that function, and call a memoized version of the superclass function. An example:

**A.m**

```matlab
classdef A < handle
    methods
        function res = foo(obj, arg)
            disp('class A')
            res = arg;  % expensive calculation
        end
    end
end
```

**B.m**

```matlab
classdef B < A
    methods
        function obj = B()
            fn = @foo@A;
            obj.foo_m = memoize(fn);
        end
        function res = foo(obj, arg)
            disp('class B')
            obj.foo_m(arg)
        end
    end
end
```

Now it complains about a an invalid operator in line:
`fn = @foo@A;`

Furthermore I have the feeling that this might be an issue also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21413098/1768422

How to solve this in an elegant/transparant way?